# Определитель матрицы

Tags: c, математика, матрицы, численные-методы

Из-за деления на нуль программа выдает -nan в случае, если первый элемент матрицы нулевой. Как можно было бы исправить эту ошибку ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    int n, i, j, k;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    double a[n][n], t, det;
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                scanf("%lf", &a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        for(k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            for(i = k+1; i < n; i++) {
                t = a[i][k] / a[k][k];
                a[i][k] = 0;
                    for(j = k+1; j < n; j++) {
                        a[i][j] = a[i][j] - t * a[k][j];
                    }
            }
        }
        det = 1.0;
        for(k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            det = det * a[k][k];
        }
        printf ("det: %lf\n", det);
}
```

Comment: Метод Гаусса с выбором главного элемента вам в помощь. Знаете такое свойство определителя - *если две строки (или два столбца) поменять местами, то знак определителя изменится на противоположный*? Вот и подумайте... Кстати, нолик может выскочить и позже, не только в первом элементе матрицы.

Comment: А где в определителе матрицы нужно деление?

Comment: @Alexey Ten нужно посчитать определитель матрицы, приведя ее к ступенчатому виду методом Гаусса, при реализации данного метода и происходит деление

Comment: @Harry Не могли бы вы показать как это сделать корректно, так как у меня не выходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
double GaussDet(double**m, int n)
{
    double det = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        double mx = fabs(m[i][i]);
        int idx = i;
        for(int j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
            if (mx < fabs(m[i][j])) mx = fabs(m[i][idx = j]);
        if (idx != i)
        {
            for(int j = i; j < n; ++j)
            {
                double t = m[j][i];
                m[j][i] = m[j][idx];
                m[j][idx] = t;
            }
            det = -det;
        }
        for(int k = i+1; k < n; ++k)
        {
            double t = m[k][i]/m[i][i];

            for(int j = i; j < n; ++j)
                m[k][j] -= m[i][j]*t;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) det *= m[i][i];
    return det;
}
```

Полный пример - https://ideone.com/zSD3Y2